Matching solutions of the heat equation in cylindrical coordinates
Difficulty Matching PDE Solutions at $R_{0}$ Using MATLAB Integration
Hello,
I am working on solving a boundary value problem involving a PDE (heat equation in cylindrical coordinates with two Neumann conditions and Dirac delta function as an IC) with different regimes for $2\epsilon<r<R_{0}$ and $R_{0}<r<R^{*}$
where r is the radial coordinate, $\epsilon$ is of the order of 0.4 $\mu\textrm{m}$, $R_{0}$ is of the order of 1.4 $\mu\textrm{m}$, $R^{*}$ is of the order of 2.4 $\mu\textrm{m}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p(r,t)}{\partial t}
=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
2D \left(\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial r^2} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right)  \quad\mbox{ for }\quad 2\epsilon<r<R_{0}
\\
2D \left(\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial r^2} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right) -2\kappa r\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \quad \mbox{ for }\quad R_{0}<r<R^{*}
\end{array}\right.
 \end{equation}
​
$\kappa$ is of the order of 1$s^{-1}$ and $D$ in the order of 0.33$\frac{\mu\textrm{m}^{2}}{s}$. The BCs are: $\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} (2 \epsilon,t)=0, \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} (R^{*},t)=0$. The IC is a Dirac delta function at $R_{0}$: $p(r, 0) = \frac{\delta(r - R_0)}{2\pi R_0}$.
The problem requires matching solutions at $R_{0}$, using continuity condition for the function and demanding the integration equals to 1 of the eigenfunctions (normalization condition). However, my MATLAB implementation does not yield solutions that match well (there is a certain jump there) at $R_{0}$.
I suspect there may be an issue in my approach and would appreciate any guidance. These are the solutions for each region :
The general solution inside $R_{0}$:
$
R_{1}(r) = C_1 M\left(-\frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 1; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^{2} \right) + C_2 M\left(1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^{2} \right),
$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are coefficients to be determined, and $M$ is the confluent hypergeometric function $M(a, b; x)$ defined as $M(a, b; \phi) = 1 + \frac{a}{b} \, \phi + \frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)} \, \frac{\phi^2}{2!} + \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)} \, \frac{\phi^3}{3!} + \cdots$
Continue: $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues.
We have the BC:
$ R_{1}'(r = 2\epsilon) = 0 $.
$
C_1 \left( -\frac{\lambda D}{2k} \right) M\left( 1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right) + C_2 \frac{1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}}{2} M\left( 2 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 3; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right) = 0.
$
$
C_{1} = \frac{\frac{1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}}{2}M\left( 2 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 3; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)}{\frac{\lambda D}{2k}M\left( 1-\frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)}C_{2} .
$
$
R_{1}(r) = C_{2}\left[\frac{\frac{1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}}{2}M\left( 2 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 3; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)}{\frac{\lambda D}{2k}M\left( 1-\frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)} M\left(-\frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 1; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^{2} \right) +  M\left(1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^{2} \right)\right].
$
Outside of $R_{0}$:
$
R_{2}(r) = A J_0(\alpha r) + B Y_0(\alpha r)
$
where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the zeroth order first and second kind Bessel function and  and $A$ and $B$ are coefficients to be determined and  is the square root of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ as  $\alpha^{2}=\lambda$.
Boundary condition:
$
\frac{dR_{2}(r)}{dr}\bigg|_{r = R^*} = 0
$
Substituting:
$
- A \alpha J_1(\alpha R^*) + B \alpha Y_1(\alpha R^*) = 0
$
$
\Rightarrow A J_1(\alpha R^*) = B Y_1(\alpha R^*)
$
$
\Rightarrow B = -\frac{J_1(\alpha R^*)}{Y_1(\alpha R^*)} A
$
Final solution:
$
R_{2}(r) = A \left[ J_0(\alpha r) - \frac{J_1(\alpha R^*)}{Y_1(\alpha R^*)} Y_0(\alpha r) \right]
$
For matching we demand:
$
R_{1}(R_{0}) = R_{2}(R_{0})
$
and the normalization condition as (when assuming $C_{2}$ to be zero which should be correct (as we care only about the ratio of the coefficients as later on they are ''swallowed'' when implementing the IC)):
$
\int_{2\epsilon}^{R_0} R_1^2 \exp\left(-\frac{\kappa}{2D} r^2\right) \, dr + A^2 \int_{R_0}^{R^*} R_2^2 r \, dr = 1
$.
So I start with isolating $A$:
$A = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - \int_{2\epsilon}^{R_0} 
\left[
\frac{\frac{1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}}{2} M\left( 2 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 3; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^2 \right)}
{\frac{\lambda D}{2k} M\left( 1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2k}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^2 \right)}
M\left(-\frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 1; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^2 \right)
+ M\left( 1 - \frac{\lambda D}{2\kappa}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}r^2 \right)
\right]^2
\exp\left(-\frac{\kappa}{2D} r^2\right) \, dr}
{\int_{R_0}^{R^*} 
\left[
J_0(\alpha r) - \frac{J_1(\alpha R^*)}{Y_1(\alpha R^*)} Y_0(\alpha r)
\right]^2 r \, dr}}.$.
Then, to obtain the eignevalues I substitute in the continuity condition:
$\left[ \frac{\frac{1 - \frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2k}}{2}M\left( 2 - \frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2k}, 3; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)}{\frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2k}M\left( 1-\frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2k}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(2\epsilon)^{2} \right)} 
M\left(-\frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2\kappa}, 1; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(R_{0})^{2} \right) +  
M\left(1 - \frac{\alpha^{2}_{i} D}{2\kappa}, 2; \frac{\kappa}{2D}(R_{0})^{2} \right) \right]
 =A\left[ J_0(\alpha_{i} R_{0}) - \frac{J_1(\alpha_{i} R^*)}{Y_1(\alpha_{i} R^*)} Y_0(\alpha_{i} R_{0}) \right]$.
Then I substitute what I got for $A$ (which I'm not sure if the plus sign, minus sign or both is/are correct) and solve for the eigenvalues with the build-in MATLAB function $\bf{fsolve}$. I can clrearly see from my plots that there is a relatively high jump between the two regions which I'm not happy about. I'll be glad if someone could advice from experience in matching solutions of PDEs.
Below is the MATLAB code and attached also the figures obtained so far.

Thanks!
Roi

close all
clear all
clc

% Parameters
R0 = 1.6;       % Inner radius
R_star = 2.4;   % Outer radius
D = 0.33;       % Diffusion coefficient
epsilon = 0.4;  % Small cutoff
kappa = 1;      % Reaction coefficient

% Special functions (placeholders for the confluent hypergeometric function M)
M = @(a, b, x) hypergeom(a, b, x); % MATLAB has the hypergeom function

J0 = @(x) besselj(0, x);
J1 = @(x) besselj(1, x);
Y0 = @(x) bessely(0, x);
Y1 = @(x) bessely(1, x);

% Define R1(r)^2 as a function of alpha
R1_squared = @(r, alpha) ( ...
    ( (1 - (alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa)) / 2 * M(2 - (alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 3, (kappa / (2 * D)) * (2 * epsilon)^2) ...
    ./ ((alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa) * M(1 - (alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 2, (kappa / (2 * D)) * (2 * epsilon)^2)) ...
    .* M(-(alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 1, (kappa / (2 * D)) * r.^2) ...
    + M(1 - (alpha.^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 2, (kappa / (2 * D)) * r.^2) ) ).^2;

% Define R2(r)^2 as a function of alpha
R2_squared = @(r, alpha) ( ...
    besselj(0, alpha .* r) - (besselj(1, alpha .* R_star) ./ bessely(1, alpha .* R_star)) .* bessely(0, alpha .* r) ).^2;

% Define the equation to solve for alpha
equation = @(alpha) ...
    ( ...
        besselj(0, alpha .* R0) - ...
        (besselj(1, alpha .* R_star) ./ bessely(1, alpha .* R_star)) .* bessely(0, alpha .* R0) ...
    ) .* sqrt( ...
        (1 - integral(@(r) R1_squared(r, alpha) .* exp(-kappa / (2 * D) * r.^2), 2 * epsilon, R0)) ./ ...
        integral(@(r) R2_squared(r, alpha) .* r, R0, R_star) ...
    ) ...
    - ...
    ( (1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) ./ 2 ) .* ...
    M(2 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 3, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2) ./ ...
    ((alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa) .* M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) .* ...
    M(-(alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 1, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) + ...
        M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2);
%%
%{
% Special functions (placeholders for the confluent hypergeometric function M)
M = @(a, b, x) hypergeom(a, b, x); % MATLAB has the hypergeom function

% Define the equation to solve for alpha_i (eigenvalues)
equation = @(alpha) ...
    ( ...
        (1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) ./ 2 .* ...
        M(2 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 3, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2) ./ ...
        ((alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa) .* M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) .* ...
        M(-(alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 1, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) + ...
        M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) ...
    ) ...
    - ...
    ( ...
        ( ...
            -2 * kappa * R0 * ...
            ( ...
                ((1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) ./ 2 .* M(2 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 3, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) ./ ...
                ((alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa) .* M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) .* ...
                (- (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) .* M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) + ...
                (1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) ./ 2 .* M(2 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 3, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) ...
            ) ...
        ) ...
        ./ ...
        (-2 .* D .* sqrt(alpha.^2) .* ...
            (-besselj(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R0) + ...
            (besselj(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R_star) ./ bessely(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R_star)) .* bessely(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R0)) ...
        ) ...
        + ...
        ( ...
            2 * kappa * R0 * ...
            ( ...
                ((1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa)) ./ 2 .* M(2 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 3, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) ./ ...
                ((alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa) .* M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* (2 .* epsilon).^2)) .* ...
                M(-(alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 1, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) + ...
                M(1 - (alpha.^2 .* D) ./ (2 .* kappa), 2, (kappa ./ (2 .* D)) .* R0.^2) ...
            ) ...
        ) ...
        ./ ...
        (-2 .* D .* sqrt(alpha.^2) .* ...
            (-besselj(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R0) + ...
            (besselj(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R_star) ./ bessely(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R_star)) .* bessely(1, sqrt(alpha.^2) .* R0)) ...
        ) ...
    ) .* ...
    (besselj(0, alpha .* R0) - ...
     (besselj(1, alpha .* R_star) ./ bessely(1, alpha .* R_star)) .* bessely(0, alpha .* R0));
%}
%%

% Initial guesses for finding roots
% initial_guesses = [linspace(1e-4, 1e-3, 10),linspace(1e-3, 1e-2, 10),linspace(1e-2, 1e-1, 10),linspace(1e-1, 1e0, 10),linspace(1, 50, 100)]; % Array of initial guesses
initial_guesses = [linspace(1e-1, 1e0, 10),linspace(1, 50, 50)]; % Array of initial guesses
alpha_values = []; % Store distinct roots
tolerance = 1e-2;  % Minimum difference between roots

% Find eigenvalues (alpha values)
for guess = initial_guesses
    root = fsolve(equation, guess, optimoptions('fsolve', 'Display', 'none'));
    if isempty(alpha_values) || all(abs(alpha_values - root) > tolerance)
        alpha_values = [alpha_values, root];
    end
    if length(alpha_values) >= 10, break; end
end

% Double-check alpha values
valid_alpha_values = [];
for i = 1:length(alpha_values)
    if abs(equation(alpha_values(i))) < 1e-2
        valid_alpha_values = [valid_alpha_values, alpha_values(i)];
    end
end

disp('Validated alpha_i values (|equation(alpha)| < 1e-3):');
disp(valid_alpha_values);

% Radial functions
r_range1 = linspace(2 * epsilon, R0, 100); % Region 1
r_range2 = linspace(R0, R_star, 100);      % Region 2

% Define radial functions
R1 = @(r, alpha) ...
    ( (1 - (alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa)) / 2 ) .* ...
    M(2 - (alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 3, (kappa / (2 * D)) * (2 * epsilon)^2) ./ ...
    ((alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa) .* M(1 - (alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 2, (kappa / (2 * D)) * (2 * epsilon)^2)) .* ...
    M(-(alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 1, (kappa / (2 * D)) * r.^2) + ...
    M(1 - (alpha^2 * D) / (2 * kappa), 2, (kappa / (2 * D)) * r.^2);

R2 = @(r, alpha) ...
    besselj(0, alpha * r) - (besselj(1, alpha * R_star) / bessely(1, alpha * R_star)) * bessely(0, alpha * r);

% Compute integrals and normalize radial functions
coefficients1 = zeros(size(valid_alpha_values));
coefficients2 = zeros(size(valid_alpha_values));

% Progress bar for coefficients computation
h1 = waitbar(0, 'Calculating coefficients...');
for i = 1:length(valid_alpha_values)
    alpha = valid_alpha_values(i);

    % Compute R1 and R2 at R0
    R1_at_R0 = R1(R0, alpha);
    R2_at_R0 = R2(R0, alpha);

    % Compute the coefficients directly using the integral formulas
    coefficients1(i) = (1 / (2 * pi * R0)) * (R1_at_R0 * exp(-kappa ./ (2 .* D) .* R0.^2) / trapz(r_range1, R1(r_range1, alpha).^2 .* exp(-kappa ./ (2 .* D) .* r_range1.^2)));
    coefficients2(i) = (1 / (2 * pi)) * (R2_at_R0 / trapz(r_range2, R2(r_range2, alpha).^2 .* r_range2));

    waitbar(i / length(valid_alpha_values), h1);
end
close(h1);

% Plot the first radial component (Region 1) after normalization
figure(1);
hold on;
colors = jet(length(valid_alpha_values)); % Color map for eigenvalues
for i = 1:length(valid_alpha_values)
    alpha = valid_alpha_values(i);
    R1_normalized = coefficients1(i) * R1(r_range1, alpha);
    plot(r_range1, R1_normalized, 'Color', colors(i, :), 'LineWidth', 2);
end
xlabel('$r$', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 16);
ylabel('$R_1(r)$ (Normalized)', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 16);
title('Normalized Radial Component $R_1(r)$ in Region 1', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 18);
colorbar;
grid on;

% Plot the second radial component (Region 2) after normalization
figure(2);
hold on;
for i = 1:length(valid_alpha_values)
    alpha = valid_alpha_values(i);
    R2_normalized = coefficients2(i) * R2(r_range2, alpha);
    plot(r_range2, R2_normalized, 'Color', colors(i, :), 'LineWidth', 2);
end
xlabel('$r$', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 16);
ylabel('$R_2(r)$ (Normalized)', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 16);
title('Normalized Radial Component $R_2(r)$ in Region 2', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 18);
colorbar;
grid on;

% Define the full range for plotting
r_range_total = linspace(2 * epsilon, R_star, 200);

% Compute the matched solution R(r)
R_matched_R1 = zeros(size(r_range_total)); % Contribution from R1
R_matched_R2 = zeros(size(r_range_total)); % Contribution from R2

% Loop over each eigenvalue and add contributions from R1 and R2
for i = 1:length(valid_alpha_values)
    alpha = valid_alpha_values(i);

    % Compute the contribution for each range
    R1_contribution = coefficients1(i) * R1(r_range_total(r_range_total <= R0), alpha);
    R2_contribution = coefficients2(i) * R2(r_range_total(r_range_total > R0), alpha);

    % Combine the two contributions
    R_matched_R1(r_range_total <= R0) = R_matched_R1(r_range_total <= R0) + R1_contribution;
    R_matched_R2(r_range_total > R0) = R_matched_R2(r_range_total > R0) + R2_contribution;
end

% Combine the matched solution for the full range
R_matched = R_matched_R1 + R_matched_R2;

% Plot the matched solution
figure(3);
hold on;

% Plot R1 part
plot(r_range_total(r_range_total <= R0), R_matched_R1(r_range_total <= R0), ...
    'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'b', 'DisplayName', '$R_1(r)$');

% Plot R2 part
plot(r_range_total(r_range_total > R0), R_matched_R2(r_range_total > R0), ...
    'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'r', 'DisplayName', '$R_2(r)$');

% Styling the figure
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Inches', 'Position', [0, 0, 9.8, 7.5], 'PaperUnits', 'Inches', 'PaperSize', [9.8, 7.5]);
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = 32; 
extraInputs2 = {'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 32};
xlabel('$r$', extraInputs2{:});
ylabel('$R(r)$ (Matched Solution)', extraInputs2{:});
title('Matched Radial Solution $R(r)$', extraInputs2{:});
legend('show', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 24, 'Location', 'best');
box on;
ax.LineWidth = 3;

grid on;
hold off;


% Compute and plot the matched full solution p(r, t)
time_values = [0:0.02:0.5, 5:5:30]; % Time points for evaluation
p_total = zeros(length(time_values), length(r_range_total)); % Store solutions

% Progress bar for solution computation
h2 = waitbar(0, 'Calculating matched solutions...');
for t_idx = 1:length(time_values)
    t = time_values(t_idx);
    p_t = zeros(size(r_range_total));
    
    for i = 1:length(valid_alpha_values)
        alpha = valid_alpha_values(i);

        % Add contributions from R1 and R2 in their respective ranges
        p_t(r_range_total <= R0) = p_t(r_range_total <= R0) + ...
            coefficients1(i) * R1(r_range_total(r_range_total <= R0), alpha) .* exp(-alpha^2 * t);
        p_t(r_range_total > R0) = p_t(r_range_total > R0) + ...
            coefficients2(i) * R2(r_range_total(r_range_total > R0), alpha) .* exp(-alpha^2 * t);
    end
    p_total(t_idx, :) = p_t; % Store the matched solution for this time
    waitbar(t_idx / length(time_values), h2);
end
close(h2);

% Plot the matched solution over time
figure(4);
hold on;
colors = jet(length(time_values)); % Color map for time points
for t_idx = 1:length(time_values)
    plot(r_range_total, p_total(t_idx, :), 'Color', colors(t_idx, :), 'LineWidth', 2);
end

% Styling the plot
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Inches', 'Position', [0, 0, 9.8, 7.5], 'PaperUnits', 'Inches', 'PaperSize', [9.8, 7.5]);
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = 32; 
extraInputs2 = {'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 32};
xlabel('$r$', extraInputs2{:});
ylabel('$p(r, t)$', extraInputs2{:});
title('Matched Solution $p(r, t)$ over Time', extraInputs2{:});
colorbar;
grid on;
box on;
ax.LineWidth = 3;
hold off;






I just embedded the code within the question (edited the post). Thanks!
Roi

For me it runs smoothly. Pay attention that when you use handle (for example in : R2_squared = @(r) (J0(alpha * r) - (J1(alpha * R_star) / Y1(alpha * R_star)) * Y0(alpha * r)).^2;) , you don't need to define alpha yet..... alpha is first calculated in line 146 : alpha = valid_alpha_values(i); .....

I don't have this problem but just add alpha in the handle.. Instead of @(r) have @(r,alpha)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are two types of Kummer functions in the code and as well in the post description. The two ''different'' Kummer functions are just two different order of the Kummer function (''order'' 1 and 2)

See eq.70 in page 243 (Polyanin 2002 - exact solutions for ODEs) for b=1 as in my case.. By the way, R2 by itself is obtained as a reliable solution in its region and same goes for R1( I solved the problem at the beginning independently).. The problem is with the matching.. Could you add your notes as for how the 2nd order Kummer's equation solution does not satisfy the ev. equation?

My solution is exactly the Tricomi function U(a,b,z) which is a superposition of M(a,b,z) and M(a+1-b,2-b,z), which is exactly what I have with b=1, $a=\frac{-\lambda *D}{2 * \kappa}$ and $z=\frac{\kappa}{2D}r^{2}$.. I think that the gamma functions before (as they are constants) can be swallowed in the solution's coefficients as I presented. So I believe I have the right solutions as it coincides with what the reference of Polyanin (see also wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).
